# Web-sql event not completed when combined with either form-submit or window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-sql

Heyo,

Basic workflow:

- Form submit button is clicked
- Submit event is captured
- Capture function runs a callback script

  - If the script returns false e.preventDefault() is called
  - ELSE Form submits

The above is all working fine. I have just provided it for context. The issue I am having is that as part of the callback script, a series of SQL UPDATE events are fired off. The script for this is below:

```
function writeNewProductDetails() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $('#productForm').children('input').length; i++) {
        var input = $('#productForm').children('input')[i];
        var inputType = $(input).attr('id').split('---');
        var inputVal = $(input).val();

        switch(inputType[1]) {
            case 'quantity' :
                localDB.webdb.runSQL('UPDATE orderLines SET "collected" = "'+inputVal+'" WHERE orderLineID = '+inputType[0])
                break;
            case 'code' :
                localDB.webdb.runSQL('UPDATE orderLines SET "code" = "'+inputVal+'" WHERE orderLineID = '+inputType[0])
                break;
        }
    }
    window.location(history(-1));
    return false;
}
```

Now a lot of this code is irrelevant to the question, the key part is the switch statement and the following two lines. The window.location and return false commands are used to avoid actually submitting the form (as the processing is already done).

Here is the crux of the issue. If I comment out the window.location(history(-1)) command and just have the function return false (ie stop the page submitting), the web-sql commands kick off and run as expected. If I leave it in, then the window seems to shift away before the sql commands have finished processing. This means that the database doesn't update.

Is this sort of issue a known problem, and is there a 'best-practice' to deal with it? I can't imagine that using the web-sql backend on form submit is a completely foreign concept?

***---EDIT---***

In the end I went with the following solution, its not the prettiest one in the world but it works.

- Firstly I defined a global variable `var queryCountWNPD = 0;` the wnpd stands for writeNewProductDetails.
- I then incremented the variable whenever a query was sent ie `queryCountWNPD++; \\ localDB.webdb.runSQL('UPDATE orderLines...`
- After that I added a callback function to the sql command `detailsWritten`
- This function (below) decrements the `queryCountWNPD` then checks if it is equal to 0. If it is then it runs the original window.history.go(-1) command.

  ```
  function detailsWritten() {
      queryCountWNPD--;

      if(queryCountWNPD == 0) {
          window.history.go(-1);
      }
  }
  ```

The answer below was credited because it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: what is `localDB.webdb.runSQL`? It should have transaction completed callback.

Comment: Its a locally defined function, I have set it up to handle being passed a callback or not. If it isn't passed one it sends it to a default function which just logs if it ran successfully or not (and whether results were returned), otherwise it is forwarded to the appropriate function

Comment: Yeah, you could not solve the problem without cooperation of that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. It looks like you're having a concurrency issue. It appears as if the JS parser is not waiting for runSQL to finish before moving on to the next statement. At which point, JS continues to execute, until you hit window.location, which instantly loads a page from the history, and you lose your context. This also means, I don't think you ever hit your return false, because window.location acts like an interrupt, it fires immediately.

Also note that control statements (for, switch, if, etc.) do not increment the stack in JavaScript. I'm not sure how this applies, but I have a funny feeling that it might matter.

See if you can put the window.location outside of this function, higher in the stack so to speak. So let this function return false, then in the caller, if false, window.location(history(-1)). Functions DO increment the stack, so the parser might wait until all calls finish before "closing off" that stack level.

Comment: Nice idea, but no luck. The call still isn't finishing. I did realise that apparently history(-1) is syntactically wrong (window.history.go(-1) is the correct term). Anyway, I remember reading somewhere that the web-sql commands are asynchronous, but I thought that that was to do with the callback, not the actual processing. I'll look into that now.

Comment: I haven't played with web SQL myself, so I'm in unfamiliar territory, but it seems like you can pass a callback function to a web SQL call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798710/how-to-make-this-websql-select-query-synchronous (I'm unsure if they're using the same API as you). 

If this is true, then you need to place all code that relies on successful execution of the SQL into the SQL callback. So your submit capture callback would be responsible for firing the SQL, then do nothing. The decision to window.location (and all your control flow) would be in the SQL callback.

Comment: Your correct, web-sql does implement a callback functionality. I am already using it extensively. This idea would 'solve' the issue, but it doesn't actually fix the root cause, which is what I am more interested in doing. Also, it falls down when you have the above code firing off 10-15 sql events, as you need to make sure that ALL of them are finished before proceeding with the page load.